# Regex pattern with parameter, wanna have special sign allowed inside word

Tags: c#, regex

Hello please advise me i need in the parameter part (only 1 time inside allowed a `>` just once.

Working one:

```
^(?<command>(name|Name))\s:\s(?<parameter>[\w@]([\s\w._@=*'^/\[\]]*[\w.^/\[\]])*(,\s[\w@]([\s\w._@=*'^/\[\]]*[\w.^/\[\]])*)*)(?<seperator>\s>>\s)*(?<description>\w([\s\w]*[\w.])*)?$
```

Not working one i thought i could implement like this but wrong:

```
^(?<command>(name|Name))\s:\s(?<parameter>[\w@]([\s\w._>@=*'^/\[\]]*[\w.^/\[\]])*(,\s[\w@]([\s\w._>@=*'^/\[\]]*[\w.^/\[\]])*)*)(?<seperator>\s>>\s)*(?<description>\w([\s\w]*[\w.])*)?$
```

**Expected Input**:

```
Name : param > eter1, parameter2 >> description
```

**Expected Output**:
CommandPart: **Name**
ParameterPart1: **param > eter1**
ParameterPart2: **parameter2**
Description: **description**

Comment: i ve updated, readable now?

Comment: Readable, yes. Understandable, no. Please show input and expected output.

Comment: there is a example row thats input visa versa output. I would in the parameter part a '>' sign allowed!

Comment: No Sir, its still not clear what you're asking. Pls explain you problem and language/platform on which you need a solution.

Comment: I tell you, it's *not* clear what you are asking. Putting input and expected output in one line is a bad idea. Put them in different lines.

Comment: sorry it was very confusing for me i ve updated again hope its clear and understandable..

Comment: `\s`,`\w` won't go inside character classes (`[...(whatever)...]` constructs). instead you have to specify alternatives like `(\s\w|[...(whatever)...]+)*` for an optional complement of a space separated word or a sequence of 'special characters'. you might wish to look into character classes ( `[[:classname:]]` ) to make your regex more readable. many engines also support some modifier to allow for multiline pattern specifiction including comments.

Comment: @collapsar That depends on the regex engine, there are several (like the one in .NET) which will handle `\s` and `\w` inside character classes.

Comment: Which programming language are you using? C#? Regexes differ between languages and/or editors, you know.

Comment: @thomas yes i do use C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your "expected input" isn't actually expected input, since your pattern will only match if `command` is replaced with `name` or `Name`.

It usually also helps to explain what doesn't go as expected, as we have no idea what you really want this regex to do.
It also really helps to state what language you're doing this in, as regex is implemented differently in almost all languages.

However, letting RegexBuddy chew on it, and adding your expected input makes me assume that your problem is that the capturing group named `parameter` eats up the remainder of the line, instead of giving up some content to `seperator` and `description`.
To fix this, you can make use of lazy multipliers (`*?`  or `+?`) like so:

```
^(?<command>name|Name)\s:\s(?<parameter>[\w@](?:[\s\w._>@=*'^/\[\]]*?[\w.^/\[\]])*?(?:,\s[\w@](?:[\s\w._>@=*'^/\[\]]*?[\w.^/\[\]])*?)*?)(?<seperator>\s>>\s)*(?<description>\w[\s\w]*[\w.]*)?$
```

Note that I also removed some numbered capturing groups, and set some to non-capturing subgroups, as I assume you didn't really want them to capture, given that you use named groups.
non-capturing subgroups are made like with `(?:something)`.

Comment: yes i ve used Name instead of command, i duno which kind of regex C# is using. About your statement it allowes multiple spaces around mine did trim aswell which is importend for me all what i want is to allow the '>' sign in the middle of a param best would be with obligatory spaces around means 'param > eter'